# Find the zero vector of a vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices called $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For my last assignment of linear algebra, I have an exercise where I have to find the zero vector of a vector space, but I am having some problems understanding what I really have to answer.

This is the problem:

> The matrix $A = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 & -2 \\ 10 & 5 \end{matrix}
>  \right)$ is a "vector" in the vector space of all $2\times 2$ matrices
>   (called by $M$). Write down the zero vector in this space, the vector
>   $\frac{1}{3}A$ and the vector $-A$. What matrices are in the smallest
>   ￼subspace containing $A$?

Since they do not give us any information on how addition and scalar multiplication is defined, I suppose that in this case the zero vector is simply the following matrix: $M_0 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}
 \right)$, since if we sum (like summing normal matrices) it to $A$, we get back $A$ again.

My question is: What exactly are they asking us?

We have just done a half lecture on vector spaces and almost no example, so I really a newbie to these things, and I hope you can clarify me, what the heck they are asking me.

Also, for the second part of the exercise: `What matrices are in the smallest subspace containing A?`, I have not clue. What does *smallest* subspace means?

Comment: How is **sum** of matrices defined? Now that you answer this, what matrix $\;B\;$ fulfills $\;A+B=A\;$ **for all matrices** $\;A\;$ ?

Comment: They're talking of "the space" of $\;2\times 2\;$ matrices over...etc., so by default it must be **the usual, standard** operations: sum between matrices and multiplication by scalar. BTW, "smallest subspace" means "in the span": the smallest subspace containing $\;A\;$ is just Span$(A)\;$ .

Comment: This could be called linear-algebraic common sense, and to know the rather well known linear space of matrices over a field. About span: it is just one of the several equivalent definitions.

Comment: Of span: the span of a set $\;S\;$ , Span$(S)\;$ , is the intersection of all the subspaces containing $\;S\;$, or the *minimal* subspace containing $\;S\;$ , or the set of all linear comibnations of elements in $\;S\;$ , etc.